# How to prevent left column from scrolling if it has reached its end only if it's bigger than viewport?

Tags: javascript, css

This is sort of a sticky behavior. Imagine you have two columns left and right.

Both columns on should stay in view port after they have finished but other is still going on.

[image]

What I want instead is:

[image]

Comment: What part are you stuck on?

Comment: all parts, attaching logic to scroll events causes jitter that is not maintainable and logic is broken, I'd have preferred non css way but that's not possible. Tried position: sticky that doesn't work either.